# Display a table as a pixel image in Lua

Tags: lua

Display a table var as a pixel image and save it in Lua

I have a table variable and it has coordinates and colors. I want to show it as a image. I try to google search, but no results I want. Do you have any suggestion for me?

```
temp = {
    {x=0,y=0,color=0x7c78a7}, --Original coordinate and its color
    {x=-1,y=0,color=0x7c78a7}, --Relative coordinate and its color
    {x=-2,y=1,color=0x6c6897},
    {x=2,y=-2,color=0x6c6897},
    {x=-2,y=4,color=0x8af296},
    {x=-1,y=3,color=0x8af296},
    {x=3,y=4,color=0x8af296},
    {x=1,y=-5,color=0x8af296},
    {x=5,y=2,color=0x8af296},
    {x=-5,y=2,color=0x8af296},
    {x=2,y=5,color=0x6e6a99},
    {x=1,y=5,color=0x6e6a99},
    {x=-2,y=5,color=0x8af296},
    {x=-3,y=5,color=0x8af296},
    {x=3,y=5,color=0x8af296},
    {x=1,y=-1,color=0x8af296},
    {x=3,y=2,color=0x5d5a7d},
    {x=-3,y=2,color=0x5d5a7d},
    {x=-1,y=2,color=0x5d5a7d},
    {x=-2,y=2,color=0x5d5a7d}
}
```

Comment: Pure Lua knows nothing about GUI and images.  You need some sort of programming environment which would expose GUI-related functions to Lua.  One way to do this in pure Lua is to create a temporary .bmp-file (its internal structure is the simplest of all the image formats) and to invoke your web-browser to display it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726430/graphics-library-on-lua answer. In addition, I can suggest CoronaLabs SDK for app graphics support. May be, this library too: https://gist.github.com/GymbylCoding/8fc95e1e8d1ce2c152ef